# How to download the xls file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here i have one button, if i click the button means i want to download the one demo.xls file,using php i did, but now i want to do codeigniter, i tried but i am not able to do? please see my below code

```
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="download-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Download Demo File
</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#download-btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url :"Staff/downloadDemoFile",
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
             },
             error:function(exception){
             alert('Exeption:'+exception);
            }
          });


});
});
</script>
```

> My controller

```
public function downloadDemoFile()
{
    if($this->session->logged_in != TRUE){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{
    $download= $this->Add_staff_model->downloadFile();
    }
}
```

> My model

```
public function downloadFile()
    { 
            $sFileName = 'demo.xls';
            header("Cache-Control: public");
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$sFileName");
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

            // read the file from disk
            readfile(UPLOAD_PATH_XLS.$sFileName);

    }
```

Comment: If your code work without codeigniter (pure php), just use the same code inside codeigniter application. Both are php, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a file from disk is pretty straightfoward using CodeIgniter *Download Helper*. Read the manual [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html).

```
public function downloadFile()
{ 
    // load the helper somewhere, i.e in the constructor.
    $this->load->helper('download'); 

    // Use it when necessary
    $sFileName = 'demo.xls'; // filename to be download. With path if necessary: /path/to/demo-xls
    force_download($sFileName, NULL);
 }
```

As a final consideration, in such a situation I wouldn't put the `downloadFile()` method in the model but in the controller itself.